# Using XNA to access GPGPU for image processing

Tags: c#, image-processing, xna, gpu, gpgpu

I'm working on some real-time image processing projects in C# and I want to utilize the GPU as much as possible.

Specifically I have several `byte[]` that contain raw bitmap data, and I need to do things like high/low pass filters, edge detection, masking, dilation, hole filling, median filters, etc. on those `byte[]` as close to 30 fps as possible (the images are pretty small, no larger that 640x480)

I know that there are other GPGPU libraries out there (Like [Cudafy](http://www.hybriddsp.com/Products/CUDAfyNET.aspx), [GPU.net](http://www.tidepowerd.com/), and [Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/)) but their EULAs either prohibit "for profit" usage of the library, or you need to purchase a license.

At the moment there are no funds for a license, so I'm trying to explore options that allow for commercial production while not costing anything, and XNA seemed to be the only option I could find that fits both criteria.

Are there any resources available on how to utilize XNA to access the GPU in a non-game setting?  Are there any other options available to access the GPU via C#?

Comment: While you could use XNA, it's a little messy. SlimDX has an DirectCompute interface and an MIT license, is that good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the author of this library, might I suggest [Brahma](http://brahma.codeplex.com/) - which is a open-source, free for commercial use library (under the Eclipse public license) on [CodePlex](http://brahma.codeplex.com/) and automagically translates/runs LINQ as OpenCL?

Of course, if you wish to use RAW OpenCL, I also have a .NET friendly but raw-API version of OpenCL [here](http://openclnet.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex and as a [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/OpenCL.Net).

Look [here](http://brahma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/92609#1697260) for an example of Brahma code (this one is for FFT).

Comment: Thank you for the links!  Will Brahma work on data in real-time? I know that HLSL shaders will work in real-time on data, except it has a lot of overhead (in the coding).

Comment: Yes, Brahma is meant for real-time and high-performance computing. Note that all the "magic" in Brahma is only the "Compile" step, at which point it becomes a regular OpenCL query and will work as fast. Of course, the LINQ syntax is the main limiter for certain types of computations. I am working to get around this using Roslyn but it will probably be a while before I can get anything concrete up there. You can try the samples to see the speedups .NET vs OpenCL code can get you on either the CPU or GPU.

Comment: I'm really liking your OpenCL.Net project.  I need raw speed and Linq (though awesome) is limiting.  I'll try this out and see what kinds of performance gains I can get :)  Thanks for pointing me to your project!  It looks great

Comment: @ananthonline spent some time playing with Brahma this morning - very, very cool. Multi-GPU support would be nice. :)

Comment: Thanks! Brahma does support multi-GPU: you only need to create the ComputeProvider(s) with the device(s) they need to target - just pass multiple devices in.

Comment: Quick question, do you have any examples using only OpenCL.Net?

Comment: No samples as such, but the unit tests show you how to get up and running http://openclnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/97338#1251578

Comment: @ananthonline ah; even better. I was in the middle of writing that before this question came up. Maybe now I'll finish my thesis before 2029.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at OpenCL via [Cloo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/). It is open source and released under the MIT license, meaning you can happily include it in proprietary packages.

OpenCL is a bit more flexible than CUDA in that kernels can run on the GPU, CPU and (in theory) cell processor on a system where it's available - think running Mono+Linux+PS3, though I haven't tried that combination.

(GPU.NET is nice in that it allows you to write kernels in C#, but at the moment they only run on NVidia GPUs. This was a deal-breaker for me since my dev laptop has an AMD chipset.)

OpenCL kernels are written in the OpenCL language, which is basically C. It's also actively supported by Intel, AMD, and NVidia.

I'm using Cloo/OpenCL+XNA for an FDTD (optics/wave physics simulation) project and it works very well. The OpenCL code operates on a 3D array on the GPU; periodically I copy the buffer back to the host for visualization in the XNA code.

There may be a way to share that data without going back and forth to the CPU, but I haven't found it and for visualization purposes the impact, at least in my application, is minimal.